# How to write '?' on .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I hope to make a forwarding a url using .htaccess

```
categoryname?page=23&sort=alpha to category.php?name=catgoryname&page=23&sort=alpha
```

but I'm not able to write the rewriteRule using the charachter `?`, I tryed to use `\?` but always the some problem it doesn't work.

Comment: RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)\?page=(.*)\&sort=(.*) category.php?name=$1&page=$2&sort=$3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The querystring must be matched in `RewriteCond`, rather than in the `RewriteRule`.  Then use `[QSA]` to append the existing query string onto the rewritten request, along with the new `name=` parameter.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If both page=, sort= *must* be present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page=(\d+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sort=([a-z]+)
# Rewrite categoryname (or other string) into category.php
RewriteRule ^(.+) category.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The above rules will *only* match if both `page=` and `sort=` are present.  If they do not need to be present to rewrite the `categoryname`, then the two `RewriteCond` can be omitted.

```
# If the page= and sort= are not *required*, omit them.
RewriteEngine On
# Rewrite categoryname (or other string) into category.php
RewriteRule ^(.+) category.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks,Now I found a new problem,there is some other page whitch has another rewrite rule,i want to keep them,if the link is one of them the rule which you wrote shouldn't be executed because there is a rule before it,is there a solution?

Comment: I finally found why,it was my fault :)